# How to protect an API endpoint for reporting client-side JS errors against spam (if even necessary)?

Tags: rest, security, spam-prevention, error-reporting

I am developing a web application with Spring Boot and a React.js SPA, but my question is not specific to those libraries/frameworks, as i assume reporting client-side JS errors to the server (for logging and analyzing) must be a common operation for many modern web applications.

So, suppose we have a JS client application that catches an error and a REST endpoint `/errors` that takes a JSON object holding the relevant information about what happened. The client app sends the data to the server, it gets stored in a database (or whatever) and everyone's happy, right?

Now I am not, really. Because now I have an open (as in *allowing unauthenticated create/write operations*) API endpoint everyone with just a little knowledge could easily spam.

I might validate the structure of JSON data the endpoint accepts, but that doesn't *really* solve the problem.

In questions like "[Open REST API attached to a database- what stops a bad actor spamming my db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356523/open-rest-api-attached-to-a-database-what-stops-a-bad-actor-spamming-my-db)" or "[Secure Rest-Service before user authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432157/secure-rest-service-before-user-authentification)", there are suggestions such as:

- **access quotas** (but I don't want to save IPs or anything to identify clients)
- **Captchas** (useless for error reporting, obviously)
- **e-mail verification** (same, just imagine that)

So my questions are:

1. Is there an elegant, commonly used strategy to secure such an endpoint?
2. Would a lightweight solution like validating the structure of the data be enough in practice?
3. Is all this even necessary? After all I won't advertise my error handling API endpoint with a banner in the app...

Comment: Why not secure the /errors endpoint with the same security you have on your API?

Comment: @DanH Because the client app (js) should always be able to send error data to the server. I am interested in any kind of error in the client app, logged-in users and visitors alike.

Comment: Are you using OAuth 2.0 with an Identity server to secure the API?

Answer (score 2):

I’ve seen it done three different ways…

1. Assuming you are using OAuth 2 to secure your API. Stand up two
   error endpoints.

   - For a logged in user, if an errors occurs you would
     hit the /error endpoint, and would authenticate using the existing
     user auth token.
   - For a visitor, you can expose a /clientError (or
     named in a way that makes sense to you) endpoint that takes the
     client_credentials token for the client app.
2. Secure the /error endpoint using an api key that would be scope for
   access to the error endpoint only.

   - This key would be specific to the
     client and would be pass in the header.
3. Use a 3rd party tool such as [Raygun.io](https://raygun.com/platform/crash-reporting), or any APM tool, such as [New Relic](https://www.newrelic.com/).